# Rounding behavior of updateSliderInput in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use the following R Shiny code to use the first slider to for updates in the second slider. However, when the `updateSliderInput` function is called, it seems to overwrite the `round = T` in the original `sliderInput`. I know that, since I am dividing by 9 in the `updateSliderInput` function, the step size will not be an integer for some values of the first slider, but is there a way to show a rounded value in the recalculated slider so that I don't get 16 digits of precision?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      p("The first slider controls the second"),
      sliderInput(inputId = "value", label = "The independent slider",
                  min = 1000, max = 1500, value = 1000, step = 100, round = T
      ),
      sliderInput(inputId = "value2", label = "The dependent slider",
                      min = 5, max = 500, value = 50, round = T
      )
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    val <- input$value

    updateSliderInput(session, "value2", value = (val * 0.3),
                      min = (val * 0.005), 
                      max = (val * 0.5), 
                      step = floor((val * 0.5) - floor(val * 0.005))/9)

  })     
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Right now, I see this, no matter what I try:

[image: What I see in the recalculated slider as-is]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it as simple as just `round`ing your `step=` values?

[image]

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    val <- input$value

    updateSliderInput(session, "value2", value = (val * 0.3),
                      min = (val * 0.005), 
                      max = (val * 0.5), 
                      step = round(floor((val * 0.5) - floor(val * 0.005))/9, 1))

  })     
}
```

You could also `floor` or `ceiling`, or even use `signif` to get a total number of digits (instead of `round`, which does digits after the decimal).

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. I could have sworn I tried that, or something similar. Thanks.